# Solr 8.11.2 Default Filters are not working. I have used below one but still its not working

Tags: java, solr, solrcloud

In Schema file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o28Lu.png)

In Solrconfig.xml:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tR9mW.png)

Is there any other way to work default filters in solr 8.11.2 and Its worked fine with solr 6.5 version. Can someone please tell me any solution for this. Thank you